# Why RecyclerView smoothScrollToPosition scrolled to 0 happens slowly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

I have `RecyclerView` and use it instead `ViewPager` with `BottomNavigationView` from support library. `RecyclerView` for nicely and comfort scroll have `PagerSnapHelper`.

And i faced with terrible and strange problem: 
when my listener for `BottomNavigationView` catches in method `onNavigationItemSelected` new position i make this:

```
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        var newPos = -1
        //little code for checked only a NEW position, the same values ignored
        recycler.smoothScrollToPosition(currentPos) //values 0, 1 and 2

        return true
    }
```

when i `smoothScrollToPosition` with `currentPos = 0` recycler scroll to First position (0) very slow (compared to other
). Time between call method `smoothScrollToPosition` and `onScrollStateChanged` (for recycler view scroll listener with parameter newState = `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`) with values 1 and 2 very small, and with value = 0 about a second (!)

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);` instead of  `recycler.smoothScrollToPosition(currentPos)`

`recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);` will not show the animation of scrolling down, the effect will be immediate.

You can also try this if you set **linearLayoutManager** for your **recyclerView**

`linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0);`

Comment: thx for answer, but scrolling without animation is a bad for my case. I try this method - `linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0)` but it not help